# How to position button in the middle

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile to create my mobile application. I have a plus button which appears like this:

[image]

The issue is that it is down, touching the list item. How do I make the button positioned midway between the list item and the horizontal line above it? I attempted to use absolute positioning using css, which did not work.

Here is my code:

```
<span style="float:left;color:black;font-weight:bold;font-size:24px"><label for="newpostbutton">Posts</label></span>
<span style="float:right;"><a href="#" data-role="button" id="newpostbutton" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext"></a></span>
<br>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="threads">
    <li>No conversations :(</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: By "absolute positioning" did you mean the `margin:auto` trick? Also it is probably not related to javascript nor jQuery ...

Comment: display: inline-block

Comment: ...and remove the `<br>` tag too. Use padding or margin for vertical spacing.

Comment: That did not work @Sigma

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g9UM4/2/ See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nshah, you can always give your button a negative margin-top and play around with the numbers. But it looks like there is probably more going on with the default button styles. I would look there first.

```
margin-top: -15px;
```

Comment: using this method, won't the output differ for different screen resolutions?

Comment: It's possible. But right now I can only think that a 15px vertical adjustment shouldn't make that much difference since it is a vertical adjustment and not a horizontal. Test and see. That's my favorite way of proving a theory. :) BTW, if my answer helps you out, could you please accept or vote it up? Thanks!

Comment: thanks, it doesn't make much of a difference as you said

Answer (score 1):

The floated elements needed  to be cleared.

div {
     overflow:hidden;
   }

```
<div>
    <span style="float:left;color:black;font-weight:bold;font-size:24px"><label for="newpostbutton">Posts</label></span> <span style="float:right;"><a href="#" data-role="button" id="newpostbutton" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext"></a></span>
</div>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="threads">
    <li>No conversations :(
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g9UM4/2/